# Django: can't set password for superuser on command line

Tags: django, command-line, django-manage.py

In the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), I'm at the part that says "You'll see a message for each database table it creates, and you'll get a prompt asking you if you'd like to create a superuser account for the authentication system. Go ahead and do that." I'm using Django 1.2.3.

In case it's relevant, I'm using SQLite, and in the settings file under mysite, I didn't set a password because you're supposed to leave it blank for SQLite. But right now I'm setting up the superuser account in the command line and it's demanding that I set a password. And it won't let me type.

So I leave it blank, and hit enter (which does work), and it asks me to confirm my password. I hit enter again. And it tells me, "Error: Your passwords didn't match."

Is there a reason it won't let me enter any text? Is there a way to get around this? This is just a development server, so I'm OK if the solution involves not setting a password at all, but it's not letting me do that either.

**OK, so I know I have to enter something non-empty.** The problem is, the command line is literally not letting me type there. I hit keys and the little blinking underscore doesn't move. All it will allow me to do is hit enter while it's still blank, but then the empty passwords don't match. I want to know why it's not letting me type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not suppose to see the password you are typing. Just type your password, repeat exactly same password when prompted and you should be ok.

Comment: Oh wow, OK. I'd never really used command line before, thank you. I'll accept your answer in seven minutes when it lets me; thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The Django superuser password is independent of the password used to authenticate with the database server. The reason it won't let you set a non-blank password is because it's a security risk; Django doesn't care that your app will never see public use.

Comment: I would, but it's literally not letting me type. The little underscore it blinking and I hit keys but they just don't register there. The only thing that does register is hitting enter while it's still blank, but then the command line says the passwords don't match.

Comment: @user460847: They don't show, but they do get recorded. This is to prevent shoulder-surfers from seeing the password on the screen.

Comment: Makes sense, I just figured they would have asterisks or circles or something. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

The password for the authentication module is separate from your database.  You'll have to set a non-blank password for the superuser.